# How can check if two Uris point to the same file in Android?

Tags: android, uri

Using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT or ACTION_GET_CONTENT, I can get a Uri to a file in the internal or external storage of a phone. Using `Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path));` I can get another Uri to the same file. The Uri s are different (if I convert them to String) but they point to the same file.

How can check if two Uri s point to the same file?

Comment: Delete the file using one uri. Then try to read the file from the other uri.

Comment: @blackapps I don't want to lose the file. I want just to check if the Uri has changed. Also deleting may not be possible using uris.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is impractical:

- There is no requirement for the user to select a file on the filesystem (e.g., select content from Google Drive, select content from other cloud providers, select content from an encrypted data store)
- Even if the user does, there is no requirement for there to be a way to derive a filesystem path from the `Uri`, which is what you would need to compare a `content` `Uri` from those `Intent` actions with a `Uri` created by `Uri.fromFile()`

Comment: Assuming that the two uris point to files in internal storage of a phone, How can I check if the two Uris point to the same file in internal stroage?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: That is covered by the second bullet in my answer.